Issue with setting up KSQLDB locally with Remote Kafka Cluster
I'm trying to set up KSQLDB locally and connect it to remote kafka server running on upstash. But, after configuring the credentials, I'm not able to connect to the kafka server.
I installed KSQLDB using docker by following the instructions given in the official docs. (https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/installing/)
In order to connect to the external kafka server, I have created a .properties file and mounted it as a volume in the ksql-server container.
Below is the docker-compose.yml file that I'm using.
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:${CP_VERSION}
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:${CP_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:${CP_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092


  primary-ksqldb-server:
    image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-server:${KSQL_VERSION}
    hostname: primary-ksqldb-server
    container_name: primary-ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./ksql-server.properties:/etc/ksqldb/ksql-server.properties

  additional-ksqldb-server:
    image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-server:${KSQL_VERSION}
    hostname: additional-ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - primary-ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "8090"
    environment:
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8090
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
    volumes:
      - ./ksql-server.properties:/etc/ksqldb/ksql-server.properties

  # Access the cli by running:
  # > docker-compose exec ksqldb-cli  ksql http://primary-ksqldb-server:8088
  ksqldb-cli:
    image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:${KSQL_VERSION}
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - primary-ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

Below is my ksql-server.properties file.
bootstrap.servers=sensible-condor-6169-us1-kafka.upstash.io:9092
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
  username="***" \
  password="***";

Now when I open KSQLDB CLI, i'm getting below error.
WARNING: Could not identify server version.
         Non-matching CLI and server versions may lead to unexpected errors.

Server Status: <unknown>

Having trouble? Type 'help' (case-insensitive) for a rundown of how things work!


*************************************ERROR**************************************
Remote server at http://primary-ksqldb-server:8088 does not appear to be a valid
KSQL server. Please ensure that the URL provided is for an active KSQL server.

The server responded with the following error:
Error issuing GET to KSQL server. path:/info
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
        Connection refused: primary-ksqldb-server/172.24.0.5:8088
Caused by: Could not connect to the server. Please check the server details are
        correct and that the server is running.
********************************************************************************

There is nothing in container logs as well.

The issue is that you are referring your primary ksqldb server to a new Kafka instance in your docker-compose.yml. If you already have an existing remote Kafka cluster all you need to do is reference it in your docker-compose.yml such that
KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: sensible-condor-6169-us1-kafka.upstash.io:9092

Your docker-compose.yml should look like this (please double check my indentation)
---
version: '2'
services:
  primary-ksqldb-server:
   image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-server:${KSQL_VERSION}
   hostname: primary-ksqldb-server
   container_name: primary-ksqldb-server
   depends_on:
    - schema-registry
   ports:
    - "8088:8088"
   environment:
     KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
     KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: sensible-condor-6169-us1-kafka.upstash.io:9092 #consider checking if it is reachable over this name/port
     KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
     KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
     KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
   volumes:
    - ./ksql-server.properties:/etc/ksqldb/ksql-server.properties

  additional-ksqldb-server:
   image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-server:${KSQL_VERSION}
   hostname: additional-ksqldb-server
   depends_on:
    - primary-ksqldb-server
   ports:
    - "8090"
   environment:
    KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8090
    KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: sensible-condor-6169-us1-kafka.upstash.io:9092 #consider checking if it is reachable over this name/port
    KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
   volumes:
    - ./ksql-server.properties:/etc/ksqldb/ksql-server.properties

  ksqldb-cli:
   image: ${KSQL_IMAGE_BASE}confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:${KSQL_VERSION}
   container_name: ksqldb-cli
   depends_on:
     - primary-ksqldb-server
   entrypoint: /bin/sh
   tty: true

